# Button with MouseRightButtonUp EventTrigger and a child Button with ContextMenu in ControlTemplate firing event AND bringing up Context Menu

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a control tree like so (properties removed for brevity):

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <Border>
      <Button>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
          <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseRightButtonUp">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding SelectCommand}" />
          </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <Button.Template>
          <ControlTemplate>
            <DockPanel>
              <Button>
                <Button.ContextMenu>
```

and I am struggling to stop the SelectCommand firing when the inner button is right-clicked to bring up the Context Menu.

Is there a way to do this without having to implement a custom ContextMenu?

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How would you tell the difference between _right-click to bring up the Context Menu_ and one to run `SelectCommand`?

Comment: Ideally, if they right-click the inner button (the one with the context menu) it should ONLY show the context menu and not fire the Select Command (this is currently doing both). If they click anywhere else on any of the controls rendered for the outer button OTHER THAN on the inner button, I would like ONLY the Select Command to fire (this is currently working). Hope that is clear.